# How to sort this rebol domain names block on date?

Tags: rebol

I want to sort this block on date column:

```
["domain1.com" 18-Jan-2011 #"^/" 
"domain2.com" 20-Aug-2011 #"^/" 
"domain3.com" 23-Dec-2011 #"^/" 
"domain4.com" 22-Sep-2011 #"^/"]
```

I can't see how to really do so with sort/skip function explained here, it's not crystal clear for me:
http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wsort.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got groups of three fields, and you want to sort on field 2?

This should do it:

```
data: [
    "domain1.com" 18-Jan-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain2.com" 20-Aug-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain3.com" 23-Dec-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain4.com" 22-Sep-2011 #"^/"
   ]

 sort/skip/compare data 3 2
```

Comment: Ah, never absorbed you could use just an offset there.  Still even in latest r3 *sort/skip/compare/all ["a" 2 "b" 1] 2 func [a b] [print a print b]* seems to be doing the wrong thing (prints a on one line and b on one line)

Comment: Thanks that seems obvious afterwards the help should be as clear as you :)

Comment: @hostile glad this made you discover a potential bug in R3; as for me I'm still using R2.

Comment: You can use more than one offset too.... sort/skip/compare data 3 [2 1] .... would sort by date then by domain.  The /compare func method is useful when you need even more fine-tuning on how you chose the sort ordering,

Answer (score 3):

You want the `/all` refinement used with a comparator function.  That gets it to pass the subseries (which is as long as the skip length) to the comparator as the "record", instead of just passing the first element of that series.

```
>> sort/skip/compare/all ["domain1.com" 18-Jan-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain2.com" 20-Aug-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain3.com" 23-Dec-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain4.com" 22-Sep-2011 #"^/"] 3 func [a b] [
        (second a) < (second b)
    ]

== ["domain1.com" 18-Jan-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain2.com" 20-Aug-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain4.com" 22-Sep-2011 #"^/" 
    "domain3.com" 23-Dec-2011 #"^/]
```

It works in Rebol 2 but in the version of Rebol 3 I'm currently running, it's not working.  That's a bug.